# Is it possible route the traffic from an internal static IP to a cloud function/cloud run in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I'm trying to connect my app deployed in GCP cloud functions to on premises service through a VPN Tunnel. The problem is that the on premises VPN Tunnel config only accept ONE local static IP on my side of the tunnel and not a range of internal ips.

I could achieve this deploying a VM Instance with an static internal IP but but I want to keep the advantages of a cloud function/cloud run environment.

Is there any way to route the traffic from my internal static IP like 10.160.11.75 to a cloud function/cloud run service?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access On Prem resource through VPN and private IP in egress (I mean from your Cloud Functions to your On Prem) you must set up a [VPC Connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) on your service.

If it's in ingress mode, from your On Prem to your Cloud FUnctions, your VPN connection must land in the project of your Cloud Functions. You can even set the [ingress of the cloud function to Internal](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings) to be sure that the Cloud Functions in only accessed from the VPC

Note: I think in preview the shared VPC also work. So, if you use a shared VPC with your Cloud Functions project and your VPN project, it will also work.

Comment: But I can´t assign an static internal IP to the cloud function or the vpc connector, when you create the VPC connector you must assign a range of ips, and I think that the cloud function will use a different one from that range in each invocation. My internal ip (10.160.11.75) is registered in the VPN Tunnel config and the only traffic accepted from/to this internal IP

Comment: That's the trick. I never tested with On Prem and VPN connexion, but you have to be able to resolve the Cloud Functions URL, even if you go through internal connection, Google Cloud network will resolve the routing to reach the Cloud Functions. So, let the port 53 open to the internet, to resolve the domain name. And then route all the traffic through the VPN, it should work.